# installing maven 2.2.1 in eclipse JUNO?

Tags: java, maven-2, eclipse-juno

I am new in java please help me how to install maven 2.2.1 in eclipse JUNO?

Comment: Why in heaven's name are you trying to put a `blink` tag in there? (Thankfully, Chrome doesn't render `blink` tags.) I've removed it. Please don't do that again.

Comment: Note: It's recommended to use Maven 3 as it has been designed to work better than v2.x with IDEs such as Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this [page](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) (this is official maven download page). Choose version that you want to install. Install it. If you use Windows extract files in C drive. Then go to System Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables and add there MAVEN_HOME variable with path like this `D:\Java\apache-maven-3.0.4` than add into PATH variable this `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;`. This help to install maven on your machine. Then as say @Joe2013 `Go to Eclipse-->Help-->Eclipse Market Place` and write **maven** and you will sea `Maven Integration Plugin`. Install it and you configured eclipse with maven)

**UPDATE**
for your second question

may be you forget to add to your pom.xml this:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.maventest.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: thanks for your help!  but when i run mvn operation in command this err is shown:     Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classwords.launcher.Launcher

Answer (score 1):

Go to Eclipse-->Help-->Eclipse Market Place and you should be able to install Maven